# Why does the value of this List change when I change another List?

Tags: c#

hi i already had a similar problem but unfortunately i can't figure it out how to solve it. I have a `List<int> tmpList` and a `List<int> tmpSpeicherListe` where i want to copy my `tmpList` so i can edit my `tmpList` and reset it when i need to.

I want to edit `tmpList` multiple times in for loop and reset it everytime while loop repeats but if i remove one value of `tmpList` at position x it removes the value of tmpSpeicherListe at position x too. So where should i place the declaration of `List<int> tmpSpeicherListe = tmpList;` or where else is the mistake?

ps: this is just a part of my code

```
//...

List<int> tmpSpeicherListe = tmpList;            //copy tmpList
int basisPosition = 2;
int counter2 = 0;

while(counter2 + 2 < tmpList.Count - 1)
{
    basis = tmpList[basisPosition];
    for (int m = 1; m < tmpList.Count - basisPosition; m++)
    {
        int speicher = tmpList[basisPosition + m];
        bool vorhanden = false;
        for (int n = 0; n < intKombinierbar[basis].Length; n++)
        {
            if (intKombinierbar[basis][n] == speicher)
            {
                vorhanden = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(vorhanden == false)
        {
            tmpList.RemoveAt(basisPosition + m);        //edit tmpList BUT tmpSpeicherListe changes too
        }
    }


    if(tmpList.Count <= i)
    {
        tmpList = tmpSpeicherListe;            //reset tmpList
        counter2++;
        basisPosition = 2 + counter2;
                                                
    }
    else if (basisPosition == tmpList.Count - 2)
    {
        großeKombinationen.Add(tmpList);
        tmpList = tmpSpeicherListe;            //reset tmpList
        counter2++;
        basisPosition = 2 + counter2;
                                                
    }
    else
    {
        basisPosition++;
    }
}
//...
```

Answer (score 0):

You should clone `List`. You set reference of `tmpSpeicherListe`  to reference of `tmpList`. You can clone like this.

```
List<int> tmpSpeicherListe = new List<int>(tmpList);
```

Comment: If you plan on removing objects from the `tmpList` it will also remove them from the `tmpSpeicherListe` as well using this approach.